# Ejecutar función llegada a una hora concreta en Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ionic4

estoy haciendo una app en Ionic, usa Typescript como lenguaje, y Angular com framework.

Resulta que estoy añadiendo los anuncios en un banner y tengo un bloque donde si ves un anuncio oculta durante unas horas el banner, tengo todas las funciones, y tengo acceso al storage de la plataforma para guardar a la hora donde tiene que volver a mostrarse el banner.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como podria subcribirme a ese objeto hora para que justo cuando llegue la hora indicada ejecute la funcion de mostrar anuncios?

No paro de navegar para encontrar un resultado pero no soy capaz, si alguien puede ayudarme o pasarme documentacion que sirva lo agradezco muchisimo, que tengan buen dia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el componente donde se muestra el banner puedes hacer algo sencillo como crear un `interval` con javascript que evalúe cada segundo si ya es hora de mostrar el banner.

```
setInterval(()=>{
//comprobar si es hora de mostrar banner
},1000);
```

[Ejemplo con setInterval](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6z3aaj)

Para usar un observable puedes crear un servicio y dentro de este poner una función como esta:

```
observar(){
    return Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .map(()=>{ 

     //codigo que comprueba si es hora de mostrar el banner
    // si es hora return true, sino return false

      });
  }
```

Y en el componente importas el servicio y  te suscribes al observable:

```
this.service.observar().subscribe(r =>{
      if(r){ 
       alert("es hora de mostrar el banner");
      }
    });
```

[Ejemplo con observable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gwamw3)

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero lo que necesito es guardar ese valor, para que cuando el usuario cierre la app, ese tiempo siga contando es decir, que mas que un contador necesito un Observable hacia una variable Date

Comment: Entonces todavía no se está guardando la hora para mostrar de nuevo el banner?

Comment: por ahora no, pero eso no tengo problema porque en cuanto vea el anuncio con reward guardo la hora actual le añado las horas horas que quiero que se este sin banner y vuelvo a guardar la variable.mi problema es pasada esta hora que directamente se muestre, una solución es en el init del componente y guardando la fecha-hora  en el storage del movil cuando inicie compruebe si hay una hora si no hay ninguna que se muestre, si la hay si ya es mayor la actual que la borre y lo muestre pero si todavia no es la hora que el banner siga oculto.

Comment: El problema es que tendria que recargar la app para que haga todo eso entoces el Observable si que esta en todo momento escuchando pero no tengo ni idea

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo de una app ionic usando setInterval para consultar el localStorage cada segundo y que muestra un mensaje cuando el contador es igual al valor guardado en el storage.El setInterval funcionaría similar al observable, cada segundo estaría comprobando si ya es hora de mostrar el banner. No tendrías que recargar la página. Solo lo inicias en el init. Intenta y me dices si tuviste problemas.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!